# Why rather use pointer to struct than regular struct-type vars in chained list?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

In university class they taught us that if we want to create a chained list, we create a stucture and handle every part of the list as a pointer.
something like this:

```
typedef struct node_elem {
    int key;
    int value;
    struct node_elem* next;
} node;
typedef node* node_ptr; 

int main() {
    node_ptr b;
    b = (node_ptr) malloc(sizeof(node));
    b->key = 2; b->value=20;
```

I thought that's the only reliable way to write data into a struct but I just tried the following and it worked as well:

```
node a, c; // this instead of pointer, direct declaration
node_ptr b;
b = (node_ptr) malloc(sizeof(node));
a.key = 1; a.value = 10;
a.next = b;
b->key = 2; b->value = 20;
b->next = &c;
c.key = 3; c.value = 30;
```

No my question is: Why even use the pointer-variant? The other way seems to be way easier because I don't need to allocate memory separately. Either way I can iterate through the list.

Comment: By "pointer version" do you mean allocating the memory with `malloc` (i.e. the `b` variable), as opposed to creating a local variable(i.e. the `a` or `c` variables)?

Comment: Try creating a list with 1000 nodes and see for yourself :) Do you want to write down 1000 variable declarations?

Answer (score 0):

You could alloc list node in both ways: statically o dynamically and that works. But sense of use linked list is make that list grow at an arbitrary size, filling the list with arbitrary quantity of nodes.

Why do you want to make a linked list if you have static nodes?

If you dont know number of nodes: how do you declare thats nodes statically?